# c# if statement && ||

Tags: c#, if-statement

Currently I have code set up to send out an email once a URL ping takes longer than `450ms`. I want to change this so that it should only send the email once the ping was longer than `450ms` more than once so I don't end up receiving tons of emails. Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if I need to include any more code.

```
 if ((int) response >= 450) {
   SendEmailPageloadFailed(site.Name, (int) response);
 }
 }
 entities.SaveChanges();
 return Json(status);
 }
 }
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: This code looks excatly how you want it to be. So where is the question? Is there even one?

Comment: not sure what I need to add in to make it work. I am still learning c# (rookie level)

Comment: It works at the moment and sends out an email, but I want to change it so that it only sends the email out once the page hits 450ms consecutively.

Comment: "once the ping was longer than 450ms more than once " sounds like you would need a counter. If the `response > 450` count up, if "more than once " fire at will...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question. We have no context for the code snippet you have provided, and you don't seem to understand what you are doing yourself. You need to go and analyse the code yourself to see what exactly is happening. Perhaps create a few small applications yourself to learn how to code and understand what is going on before tackling something like this.

Comment: add the flag and set it to true if you already sent it, and in your condition include the flag if it is already sent or not, give it a try

Comment: @Desperado I'm not sure that will help. How is the flag stored? Can it be stored in memory, or in a database? How do we know what a "consecutive attempt" is? What should we do to allow the program to recognise a "consecutive attempt"? There simply isn't enough information to decide on a course of action.

Comment: @user1666620 it's up to you on how you think it, no need to spoon feed all. okies?

Comment: Thanks @Desperado. Will learn a bit more on c# and have a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do that (I'm not going to post the actual code because then you wouldn't learn anything):

1. Check Ping
2. If Ping is OK, reset counter. If not, increment counter.
3. Check when the last time you sent an email was. Send an email if appropriate, don't if it's not (e.g. define a minimum time-span between two emails).

Before you start coding, precisely define under which conditions you want to send an email. Write up some use cases (realistic ones and border cases) and test them against your conditions. Redefine / Repeat if necessary.